# Problem with some Normal Distribution related questions

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

so I'm familiar with normal distributions but not when one random variable W is conditional on Z and both are normally distributed. I've attached a picture of the questions. I can imagine the concepts in these questions aren't too complicated but I'm not sure how to handle them or where to start from. Would really appreciate some help!

[image]

Comment: I can give a hint for a) which if it becomes clear to you all of the questions should become clear. For a) you already know something related. It is given to you that E[W|Z=z] = z in the question. Now what do you know from basic probability and expectation rules about how to go from E[W|Z=z] to E[W], how do they relate? Remember, expectations are integrals of functions with respect of probability distributions. How do joint, marginal, and conditional distributions relate to each other?

Comment: @TyrelStokes thank you! I guess I'll try brushing up on conditional expectation and variance rules. The law of iterated expectations can be used to find E[W] from E[W|Z=z], right? A rather silly follow up to this, I didn't understand the difference between the variance given by sigma^2(w) with the '~' on top and the normal sigma^2(w). What's the relation between them?

Comment: Wait so E(E[W | Z = z]) = E(W). Now E(E[W | Z = z])  = E(z). Is E(z) = $\mu_z$? So is E(W) = E(Z)? or is E(W) = 0 as z is any constant? I'm sure I'm making some mistake.

Comment: The law of iterated expectations says that $E[E[W|Z=z]] = E[W]$. In this particular case, from what was given $E[E[W|Z=z]] = E[z] = \mu_z$ which must be the expectation that you want, $E[W]$. I understand the confusion about whether z is a constant or not. This can be alievated by explicitly writing out the integral, in this case $E[W] = E[E[W|Z=z]] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E[W|Z=z]f(z)dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}zf(z)dz$ where $f(z)$ is the normal pdf, or write the law of iterated expectation as $E[E[W|Z]]$, where it is clear that $E[W|Z]$ is a random variable.

Comment: $\tilde{\sigma^2_w}$ is just a symbol that the question writer is using to stand in for the variance of W conditional on Z = z. To relate this to the unconditional variance you will want to look at the law of total variance. This law follows from the law of iterated expectation. You will see that that unconditional variance of W will be a function of the variance of $Z$, $\sigma_z^2$ and the conditional variance $\tilde{\sigma}^{2}_w$.

Comment: Amazing! This makes things so much clearer! Really appreciate your help @TyrelStokes! Thank you so much! I think I'll keep reading up and brushing up on these concepts and the rest of the question shouldn't be an issue.